# create dynatrace custom alerts from open-telemetry traces

Tags: open-telemetry

I would like to integrate open-telemetry in dynatrace. The stable Traces are integrated in our implementation. How metrics ("timing" from "ConfigurationData.find" )can be extracted from traces to define custom alerts in dynatrace?

"ConfigurationData.find" is displayed as the Operation of span. DB is MongoDB and our service in Go.

Comment: Hello Rio, do you have OpenTelemetry metrics implemented as well?

Comment: Only we have traces as metrics is not marked stable for Go.

Comment: hmmm... I can't see a way of doing that ATM, what DB are you using? Maybe I could play around a bit with a sample to see if I can get something